# Only required validator showing up when trying to get all validators in ControlValueAccessor using ngControl

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, form-control, controlvalueaccessor

Basically I am trying to create a reusable component which implements `ControlValueAccessor` so that I can use formcontrol on it. What I am trying to do in this component is I am trying to get a hold on underlying formControl which is applied to my component e.g.

If in `.ts` file, I have -

```
let ctrl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email])
```

And in template file -

```
<app-custom-textbox [formControl]="ctrl"></app-custom-textbox>
```

Then I am trying to get all the `validators` on `ctrl` formControl in my `app-custom-textbox` component

The problem is, when I do this using `ngControl` in my custom component, only `required` validator shows up and not other applied validators e.g

Inside `custom-textbox-component.ts` -

```
constructor(@Self() @Optional() public control: NgControl) {}

ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    const control = this.control.control;
    if (control) {
        console.log(control);
    }
  }
```

This is what I get from `console.log` -

[image]

I have tried setting `setValidators({required: null})` and `control.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true })` so that it may show other validators present but that never happened.

Code is available on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmaj3m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-textbox.component.ts)

##### Question: How do I get all the validators present on underlying formControl not just required validator?

Comment: where is `formGroup`

Comment: try adding formGroup to parent form